# Computational complexity of a nested algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, big-o

Given an array a [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] let's say we have an algorithm that does the following:

```
for i in 0..a.length
  for j in 0..a.length
    ...
```

This would have a Big O runtime of O(n^2) because for each element it will traverse the entire array.

But what if the inner loop only traversed from the outer index forward?

```
for i in 0..a.length
  for j in i..a.length
    ...
```

That is, in comparison the first algo will look at n elements each iteration (outer loop). The second algo looks at:

- n elements on the first iteration
- n-1 elements on the second iteration
- n-2 elements on the third iteration
- ...
- 1 element on the last iteration

When calculating Big O runtime for this kind of algo, is it still O(n^2)?

Answer (score 10):

This is still O(n^2).  The sum 1 + 2 + ... + n is n(n+1)/2, which is O(n^2).

More generally, for any polynomial function p(n), the sum of p(1) + p(2) + ... + p(n) is O(n p(n)).  This proof is a lot harder, since you have to reason about sums of arbitrary powers of n, but it is indeed true.  This means, for example, that if you nested a third loop inside out your inner loop that ranged from j to n, the runtime would be O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

If you are given that a is that specific array, then the time complexity for that algorithm is constant (or O(1)). Maybe I read what you asked too literally, but for the tightest bound to be O(n^2), a would have to be an array like [1,2,...,n]. If a is explicitly size 10, then, the algorithm always runs in the same number of steps.

Hopefully, this answer was unnecessary, but I'm a teaching assistant for a discrete math class, and we give trick questions pretty frequently that are very similar to this. If I misunderstood the question, then I apologize for wasting your time! Also, the answer that was already posted is very good!